# Bubblesort with measure time

Tags: c

With headers...

> main.c

```
int main()
{
    double *a = NULL ,n;
    read(&a,&n);
    clock_t start,stop;
    start = clock();
    bubblesort(a,n);
    stop = clock();
    float elapsedTime = (stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("%f",elapsedTime);
    write(a,n);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

> sema.c

```
void read(int *a,int n)
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a = (int*)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    if(a == 0){printf("Error");return 0;}
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        a[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}

void bubblesort(int *a,int n)
{
    int i,j,csere;

    for(i = 0; i < n-1; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < n - i -1; ++j){
            if (a[j] > a[j + 1]){
                csere = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j + 1];
                a[j + 1] = csere;
            }
        }
    }
}
void write(int *a,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%i ",a[i]);
    }
}
```

> sema.h

```
void read(int*,int*);
void write(int*,int);
void bubblesort(int*,int);
```

I used debugger to find any of my problem.My write function is not working because it thinks the n is 0, but I input that.Also the measuring the time is not working I get zero.I really not understanding why the n is zero if I input that.

Comment: If your compiler didn't give you any warnings for the various mistakes in your code above then it's probably time to get a new compiler.

Answer (score -1):

in main, you initialized variables as double, but in other functions, getting it as integers. 
in read(), 
prototype is `void read (int *a, int *n);`
but you defined `void read(int *a, int a)`and in read(), why you are returning 0 in "if condition" since you are mentioned void type.